# Copy data table to table with a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Trying to copy on the new data from table1 into table2. I am not sure how to code it another way than this

```
INSERT table1 
SELECT x.*,y.TIMESTAM  
FROM table1 x, table2y
WHERE x.TIMESTAM > y.TIMESTAM;
```

I want to copy all the columns from table1 if the timestamp is newer (>) row 1 in table2

Comment: Can you share your table schema? It will give better idea to help you out.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d431d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you copy all newer data from table2 into table1:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE TIMESTAM > (select MAX(TIMESTAM) FROM table1);
```

Comment: I checked your aqlfiddle. The problem is your tines tan column is a text forks. Change it to a datetime and it will all work.